# I'm using struts1, about the action name

Tags: java, struts, struts1

I'm looking for the process that strusts decided which is the action name.

the web.xml config file is:

```
<url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
```

when user request "a.do" in browser, how does struts know the action name is "a" not "a.do"?

Comment: Err... cause it ignores the extension? Read the docs.

Comment: I just cannot find the right doc the description the algrithm of decided which part of the url is the action name.

Comment: Your question wasn't even readable without the formatting; might be a good idea to proofread after posting.

Comment: It removes the ".do" from the URL. Not rocket science.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with the servlet-mapping configuration

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

[Struts Configuration](http://struts.apache.org/development/1.x/userGuide/configuration.html) see section 5.4.2